# Google Sheets Remove Inconsistent Characters

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula

I would like a formula that removes the ending of each of the text so it's consistent [image]

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ysjz4B6Eh4eE5y_cYg76_CilkUena6iQDZtIIMhXSOs/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: The sample spreadsheet gives "Access denied." See [The correct way to publicly share a Google test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `regexextract()`, like this:

`=arrayformula( iferror( regexextract(A2:A, "(.+)-"), A2:A ) )`

Comment: Perfect, thank you!